# Getting closest date joining 3 tables sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have 3 tables

- Table **Test1**: Test1ID(Primary key), TestID(Foreign), Version, Test1Date, Number
- Table **Test2**: Test2ID(Primary Key), TestID(Foreign)
- Table **Test3**: Test3ID(Primary Key), Test2ID(Foreign), Test3Date, Version

Sample Data:

Test1:

`Test1ID     TestID     Version     Test1Date    Number
101         201        3           2016-05-03   45
102         201        3           2016-05-06   45
103         201        5           2016-08-01   45
104         202        2           2016-02-01   34`

Test2:

`Test2ID     TestID
501         201`

Test3:

`Test3ID     Test2ID    Version      Test3Date

601         201        NULL         2016-05-05

602         201        NULL         2016-06-08

603         201        NULL         2016-08-01`

Desired Output:

`Test3ID     Test2ID    Version      Test3Date

601         201        3            2016-05-05

602         201        3            2016-06-08

603         201        5            2016-08-01`

I want to update Test3.Version = Test1.Version where Test3.Date is the closest lesser or equal to the Test1.Date

Comment: We could guess at an answer here and probably get close but it would be really helpful if you could post some sample data and desired output. Here is a great place to see some examples. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 3):

Use `ORDER BY DATEDIFF()..LIMIT` :

```
UPDATE Test3 t
SET t.version = (SELECT TOP 1 s.version FROM Test2 s
                 WHERE s.testID = t.test3ID
                 ORDER BY ABS(DATEDIFF(DAY, s.test1Date,t.Test3Date)))
```

BTW - Why did you post `Test2` structure? Doesn't seem like you are using it.

Comment: This code has LIMIT 1 which is for mysql . This question is clearly marked as sql server.

Comment: Yea, typo .. guess I'm tired :) @SeanLange

Comment: thanks @sagi , I can't test your query at the moment but will update this post after testing.

Comment: @sagi the query is not working for me. Also I need Test2 because Test1 and Test3 are connected through Test2 i.e Test1.TestID = Test2.TestID and Test2.Test2ID = Test3.Test2ID